# "The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception." C#

Tags: c#, bitmap

I don't understand what this means:

"The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception."

Here is my Code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
namespace MyProgram
{
  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Bitmap img = new Bitmap("test.jpg");
        for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
            {

                Color pixel = img.GetPixel(i, j);

                Console.WriteLine(pixel);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Visual Studio is highlighting this saying the error:

```
 Bitmap img = new Bitmap("test.jpg");
```

Is there anyway to fix this error?

Comment: The graphic mode of the jpg file may not be supported by your graphic card.  The driver of the graphic card uses the extension of the file and the ASCII header in the file.  So start by opening up the jpg file with Notepad and see the header.  Sometimes an error like this occurs because somebody put the wrong extension on the file.  You may have a png file with a jpg extension.  Or the mode of the file isn't supported by your card.  Some drivers use just the extension, some use the ASCII header, and some use both.

Comment: Does it throw if you just call it as `Bitmap img = new Bitmap(10, 10);`? In what *environment* is this code run? What System version? What .Net Framework version? Is this actually a .Net Framework-based app, or did you choose a .Net Core app? Or a mixed project? I don't see any threading involved: is this just a *sample* code or maybe the real code is different? This error is related to GDI+ initialization. You may want to test it calling [GdiplusStartup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusstartup) (you may find the declarations on PInvoke.net)

Comment: Where is that `test.jpg` located? Because this seems like a simple case of not finding the file. Without any path specified it'll look for this in your debug or release folder, whichever mode you're compiling in.